# How to set specific width/height for view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout in xml layout file.
At runtime, I wanna create 2 text view and them add into layout.
=> I cannot set width/height for 2 text view by my specific size.
If I set `MATCH_PARENT`, it's OK.
If I set by any specific size, it's only `WRAP_CONTENT`

XML layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.androidsnipcode.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

Dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="heigh">300dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="width">600dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

onCreate() of Activity.java:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, R.dimen.heigh);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
        tv.setText("hello 1");
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        layout.addView(tv);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                R.dimen.width, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams2);
        tv2.setText("hello 2");
        tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        layout.addView(tv2);
```

Screen shot: height of first textview and width of second textview does not meet my expected (it's wrap content not my specific size)
 [image: height of first textview and width of second textview does not meet my expected]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do like this. Width/Height should be a pixel value.

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width),100);

 textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You can Read from dimens resource or hardcode a pixel value.